# Leaflet JS - AGS vector layer change opacity

Tags: jquery-ui, leaflet

I have a leaflet map that I have a bunch of vector layers (using the leaflet vector layers plugin) that I want to be able to adjust the opacity of the vectors with a slider, like jQuery UI slider.

With the code I am using below, my slider doesn't do anything. The layer is shown with opacity, but it doesn't change when the slider is moved.

How do I connect the slider to this vector layer?

```
      var poleMarker = new L.Icon({
            iconUrl: "img/markers/manhole.png",
            iconSize: new L.Point(16, 16),
            iconAnchor: new L.Point(8, 8),
            popupAnchor: new L.Point(1, -8)
        }); 

      poles = new lvector.AGS({
                url: "http://gis.ultimap.com/arcgis/rest/services/**link to my map**/1",
                fields: "*",
                scaleRange: [3, 200],
                showAll: true,
                singlePopup: true,
                esriOptions: false,     
                symbology: {
                    type: "single",
                    vectorOptions: {
                        icon: poleMarker,
                        opacity: .5
                    }
                },
                popupTemplate: '<div class="iw-content"><h3>Pole</h3><table class="condensed-table"><tr><th>ID:</th><td>{OBJECTID}</td></tr></table></div>'                 
            });

            $("#slider").slider({
                value: 50,
                slide: function(e, ui) {
                    function updateOpacity(value) {
                            poles.setOpacity(value);
                        }
                }
            });
```

All the examples I can find show this working for normal layers, but not for vector layers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this that will change the opacity of all the vectors. Since they are rendered as svg I can just target the paths that have a class of .leaflet-clickable and attach that to the slider:

```
 // Opacity Slider  
   $('#slider').slider({ 
    min: 0, 
    max: 1, 
    step: 0.01, 
    value: 1,
         slide: function(e,ui){
                 $('path.leaflet-clickable').css('opacity', ui.value)

         }                
    })
```